# Java Singleton Memory Leak specific

Tags: java, memory-leaks, singleton

My basic program is to read an excel file and store it in  a ConcurrentHashMap cache.This ConcurrentHashMap has String as key and some value Object.ThisConcurrentHashMap  has to be updated whenever the excel file is modified so as load/replace the new/old values in this Map.

Here is how I implemented it.ExcelDataFile is not a singleton but the idea is to have as few instances of ExcelDataFile as possible like may be 2  or 3.The excel file will be modified frequently like every 15 mins.

My first question is whether the ExcelDataFile'getInstance() method returns a singleton.

If its not singleton,My second concern is specific to MemoryLeaks.I know this program is weakly consistent but can it cause memory leaks as I was not using class level lock in getInstance() method.Instead i am relying on volatile feilds(origData and excelDataFile(static reference) ).

I know this is never going be singleton.Is there a race condition here when creating the instance.Meaning with a modified excel file,even after having volatile static reference and volatile origDate, can two threads end up creating two instances. Also can the static ConcurrentHashMap cause memory leaks when multiple instances are getting created.I have chosen this volatile way of pseudo singleton as the instructions wont be reordered.But i am not sure if this better than using class level lock .And also skipping class level lock on ConcurrentHashMap(as it does not make sense)

```
public class ExcelDataFile {




    public static String DATA_FILE_PATH ="/export/data.xlsx";

    private  static final Object CLASS_LOCK = new Object();

    private static volatile long origDate;
    private static volatile ExcelDataFile excelDataFile ;


    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object> dataLocalMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object>();

    private ExcelDataFile(String dataFile){
        ExcelDataReader reader = new ExcelDataReader(dataLocalMap);
        reader.readExcelFile(dataFile);

    }

    public static ExcelDataFile getInstance(){

        long newDate = getDate(DATA_FILE_PATH);

        //0L if the file does not exist or if an I/O error occurs
        if(newDate ==0){
            dataLocalMap.clear();
        }

            if(excelDataFile == null || (newDate!=origDate)){

                dataLocalMap.clear();

                excelDataFile= new ExcelDataFile(DATA_FILE_PATH);
                origDate = newDate; 

            }

        return excelDataFile;

    }





    protected static long getDate(String fileName) throws SecurityException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        long lastModifiedDate = file.lastModified();
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }


    public Object getData(String key){
        return dataLocalMap.get(key);
    }


}
```

---

```
public class ExcelDataReader {

private static final String excelSheetName="excelsheet";
private ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object> map = null;

public ExcelDataReader(){

}

public ExcelDataReader(ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object> dataMap){
    map = dataMap;
}



public ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object> readExcelFile(String excelFilePath){

    //read the excel file and  convert the rows into value objects and put them in the ConcurrentHashMap
    Object obj = new Object();
    map.put("TEST",obj);

    return map;  

}



}
```

---

This `getInstance()` method will be invoked from multiple threads and E`xcelDataFile .getData()` method will be used to obtain the cached data.

Multiple threads will be obtaining the data from this `ConcurrentHashMap` using the below code

```
public static Object getCacheData(String key){

            ExcelDataFile dataFile = ExcelDataFile.getInstance();
            Object test = null;
            if(null!=dataFile){
                              test  =dataFile.get(key);
                             }

return test;

}
```

Comment: @VinceEmigh ExcelDataFile is not a singleton, as a change of lastModifiedDate will result in the next call to getInstance returning a new instance.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Except that it is quite possible that more than one instance can exist at a time, if the results of getInstance() are never released by the caller. I agree that the intention is singleton-pattern. But intention alone doesn't make it a singleton

Comment: How can this be singleton when class level synchorization is not being used.Also can the static  ConcurrentHashMap cause memory leaks when multiple instances are getting created

Comment: I know this is never going  be singleton.Is there a race condition here when creating the instance.Meaning with a modified excel file,even after having volatile static reference and volatile origDate, can two threads end up creating two instances. Also can the static  ConcurrentHashMap cause memory leaks when multiple instances are getting created.I have chosen this volatile way of pseudo singleton  as the instructions wont be reordered.But i am not sure if this better than using class level lock .And also  skipping class level lock on ConcurrentHashMap(as it does not make sense)

Comment: This is not a singleton. If you want a singleton, turn your class into an `enum` with one instance (e.g. `ExcelDataFile.INSTANCE`). Enums are singletons by definition.